# How to generate an API reference like sklearn?

Tags: api, scikit-learn, reference, documentation

To make a python package I am writing easier to use, I am thinking of making a detailed API documentation.
The API reference of machine learning package [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.base) is the one I am trying to emulate.

So what is the right tool to make such a documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use [`sphinx`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) and extensions thereof.  See [the documentation section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#building-the-documentation) of the contributing guide, and the [documentation makefile](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/doc/Makefile).